# Centering inline-block works faulty in Opera and Chrome

Tags: css, position, center

I am trying to create three column layout and it should look like this:

```
|sidebar| |column1| |column2| |column3| |sidebar2|
```

My layout works in :IE,Firefox and Safari...

But it breaks in Opera and Chrome.

It looks like this in these browsers:

```
|sidebar| |column1|    |column2|     |sidebar2| 
                           |column3|
```

I think that the problem is in the middle column (I am giving it "display:inline-block", and "text-align:center" to the body in order to center it, but for some reason the right column is being pushed down)

I know that I am asking a lot but can you please check my [**Page**](http://www.vasinternetposao.com/wordpressdevelopment/) to see the Problem in these browsers.

If somebody knows a solution for this it would be great. Thank you!!

Comment: It looks like you have a mix of float and inline-block elements. I think the middle 3 columns can just all be inline-blocks, probably don't need to float any of them. The overall layout can be float if you want, left sidebar, middle content, right sidebar. Just float them all left with the proper width and margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your CSS for the middle column to float left.

```
#blogs_three_cols .middle_column {float:left;}
```

If you want columns to float next to each other, you need to actually float them :) You had `none` set. Doing that made the right column get all confused.

Comment: If you float though, it will mess with your margin, so instead of margin-left and margin-right both being auto, you will have to set them to .95%. ( ( 100% - 32.7 * 3 ) / 2 )

Comment: or adjust all 3 middle columns to display inline block

Answer (score 1):

do this...

```
#blogs_three_cols > div {
 float:none !important;
 display:inline-block !important;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Unless you can change the current css, you would need to override the styles with !important;

updated above.